# Тип или вид - что использовать?

Tags: употребление-слов

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать: тип или вид доставки? Например, в предложении: "Для клиентов доступны следующие типы (виды) доставки нашей почтовой службы: Эконом, Бизнес, VIP.". Спасибо"!

Comment: А это вообще вид ( тип ) именно доставки? Я не очень разбираюсь, что на почте ВИП.Курьерская почта? По-моему, здесь перечислены не названия доставки(доставка одна - экспресс), а названия тарифов в зависимости от скорости. Вот в авиаобслуживании эконом, бизнес и вип - понятно, это класс обслуживания, набор услуг, а на почте чем различаются? Может, вообще написать просто:Также наша почтовая служба предоставляет Вам следующие возможности: массовая рассылка, эконом-доставка, экспресс -доставка, услуги VIP-курьера.

Answer (score 5):

Вид - это разделение скорее по внешним признакам, а тип -  скорее по внутренним. Вид производства говорит о том, что производят, а тип - как. Тип мышления рассматривает, то как человек принимает решения, вид - с помощью чего.

Сроки доставки, различаются скорей по внутренним признакам, чем по внешним, поэтому *типы доставки*, по-моему, в данном случае подходит больше.

Answer (score 1):

В службе доставки это называется "режим": почтовые отправления весом до 20 кг (включительно) доставляются в режимах «Экспресс» и «Эконом». Отправления весом до 2 кг (включительно) доставляются в режиме «Супер-Экспресс».

Видимо, это будет выглядеть так:"Для клиентов доступны следующие типы  режимов доставки нашей почтовой службы: Эконом, Бизнес, VIP.". Или:"Для клиентов доступны следующие системы   доставки нашей почтовой службы: Эконом, Бизнес, VIP." Ведь есть же бизнес-система,VIP - система

Comment: Честно говоря, слово "режим" в таком контексте звучит совершенно не по-русски.

Comment: Но это текст почтовой службы,их термин.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что в данном случае больше годится слово "способ". "Способ доставки". Тип и вид - вообще они указывают именно на какую-то разновидность чего-либо. При этом в той же биологии тип является куда более крупной категорией, чем вид.

Comment: Способ доставки - это авиа, железная дорога, курьеры, интернет.